# What is the easiest and cheapest way to transport skis and skiing equipment (helmet, glasses, winter jacket) from Slovakia to Turin, Italy?

Tags: luggage, transportation, skiing

I have heard that there is some bus company that provides luggage transfers from one country to another, is there?

Or I was thinking about others, like post service or delivery companies. I am already in Turin. There is another possibility to get my skis my boyfriend is travelling to visit me with Wizz Air and he can take skis and stuff with him, but I find this more expensive it seems to be more than €66.

Comment: I assume you would be travelling with the skis?

Comment: Actually, she is in Torino already. She wanted me to take them with, but the company (wizzair) I am flying with would charge 66 € for extra baggage and I am not even sure if they would allow me to take skis with, cause skypicker (where I bought it) did not have an option to add "skiis" or "sport equipment" to my flight ticket.

Comment: How do you intend to travel?

Comment: She is not about to travel, she is there. I am flying with Wizzair. Skypicker just responded, they are willing to help. Price would be for 23 kg baggage + skis one way price 59 € at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[Wizzair allows passengers to carry skis and other sporting equipment as carefully-packed hold luggage](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/baggage):

> #### Sporting equipment
>
> Carriage of sporting equipment is subject to a sporting equipment fee and must be indicated and paid for during the booking process.
>
> Please read carefully the packaging requirements below. If those requirements are not fulfilled, Wizz Air will refuse carriage of the item. Please note that Wizz Air does not provide packing material. All the items mentioned below can only be carried as checked-in baggage.
>
> a) Ski Equipment, Snowboard, Surf Equipment, Golf Bags must be packed in a pouch.
>
> [...]

For this they charge a fixed sporting equipment fee. The details of the fee can be found on [the fee page of the Wizzair fee website](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/service_fees). At the time of writing the fees are:

[image: Wizzair sporting fee]

Unless you find an all-inclusive fare which includes sporting equipment (I'm not sure if these exist on Wizzair), you'll have to add the carriage fee to the cost of a plane ticket. This ought to give you a better idea about the costs involved.